# How to get child nodes after store load

Tags: extjs, tree, load, store, extjs4.1

Version: ExtJs 4.1

To change the child items I use this function:

**TreeStore** (Ext.data.TreeStore)

```
storeId  : 'treeStore',
...
constructor: function( oConfig ) {
...
this.on( 'expand', function( oObj ) {           
        oObj.eachChild(function(oNode) {
           switch(oNode.data.type) {
              case "report":
                 oNode.set('icon', strIconReport);
              break;
              case "view":
                 oNode.set('icon', strIconView);
              break;
           }
        });
     });
```

**Reload**

After removing or adding items in the tree, I reload the tree somewhere else with:

```
var oStore = Ext.getStore('treeStore');
oStore.load({
        node     : oNode,
        params   : { 
           newpath     : oNode.data.path, 
           overwrite   : true
        }
     });
```

Although it is the same store `treeStore`, after loading and expanding to the correct path, the icons are not changed since the `.on( 'expand')` function is not called. Why?

**Question**

How can I change the icons of this newly loaded store before it expands to the node path?

**What I tried**

Before calling `.load()` I tried to edit the children with `oNode.eachChild(function(oChild) {}` but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the solution, it is really easy. I do not change on `expand` anymore, rather on `load`.

So it changes icons on both expanding and loading like that:

```
this.on( 'load', function( oStore, oNode, oNodes ) { 
  // do something with the nodes 
}
```